# Return value without overwriting

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Code below is only outputting the last return and would only show the results of the last webpage in the data frame.  I have 18 pages in total to scrape and I hope I can insert price data from each page into the same data frame without overwriting each other.

```
def get_basic_info(content_list):
    basic_info = []
    for item in content_list:
        basic_info.append(item.find_all('h5'))
    return basic_info

def get_prices(basic_info):
    prices = []
    for item in basic_info:
        for i in item:
            price = i.find("span", attrs = {"class" : "price"})
        if price:
            prices.append(price.text)
          
    #print(prices)
    return(prices)

for page in range(1,18):
    base_url = "https://www.easycar.tw/carList.php?Action=search&show=col&lifting=desc&year=&year1=&page="+ str(page)
    response = get(base_url, headers=headers)
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    content_list = html_soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'caption'})
    basic_info = get_basic_info(content_list)
    prices = get_prices(basic_info)

cols = ["Price"]
data = pd.DataFrame({"Price" : prices})[cols]
data
```

Comment: where you do `prices = get_prices(basic_info)` you want that `prices` to be an array that you `.append()` into or perhaps `.extend()` depending on if you seek a list of list of prices or just one big list of prices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining prices in every iteration and writing the result to it. What you would want to do is basically before you enter the loop define `prices = []`

Then go to the `for` loop.

then do `prices.append(get_prices(basic_info))`

and when making your dataframe, you can do:

`data = pd.DataFrame({"Price" : prices})[cols]` Just as you are doing now, because then you are actually making a list.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing things up for me! I didn't realize the definition of empty set was so important! Problem solved!

Comment: @Renee If you find this answer helpful please click "accept this answer".

Comment: Sorry I am new here so i didn't know. Just clicked!